# Visualforce page button stops working when any checkbox item is selected

Tags: visualforce, checkbox

I have a Visualforce page using custom Apex as an extension. It is relatively simple, living on my "Milestone" object, displaying some related Services in a checkbox list, and my goal is to take whichever were selected and create a new separate junction object from the Milestone to the Service.

If I select 0 checkbox items, I redirect properly to the previous record page, which is where I want to be. If I select 1 or more of the checkbox items, when I click the button it redirects me to the same page. I can't figure out why. What's wrong with my createRelatedServices() function?

visualforce:

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Select the services that are applicable to this milestone.">
        <apex:pageblockSection >
            <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!selections}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!ServicesNameToID}" /> 
            </apex:selectCheckboxes>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>


    <apex:commandButton action="{!createRelatedServices}" 
                        value="Add Related Service" id="button"/>
</apex:form>
```

Apex extension:

```
public class RelatedServiceController {

 public Map<String, ID> ServicesNameToID {get;set;}
 public pse__Milestone__C milestone {get;set;}
 public pse__Milestone__C queriedMilestone {get;set;}     
 public String[] selections {get;set;}

 public RelatedServiceController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    milestone = (pse__Milestone__C)stdController.getRecord();
    getServices();
 }

 public void getServices(){
    //Need to fully query the milestone to get project ID/opp ID
    queriedMilestone = [SELECT Name, ID, pse__Project__c, pse__Project__r.pse__Opportunity__c from pse__milestone__C where id = :milestone.ID];

    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItems = [SELECT name, ID, Product2ID, ProductName__c from OpportunityLineItem  
                                              WHERE OpportunityID = :queriedMilestone.pse__project__r.pse__opportunity__c];

    ServicesNameToID = new Map<String, ID>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli: oppLineItems){
        ServicesNameToID.put(oli.ProductName__c, oli.Product2ID);
        //system.debug(oli.ProductName__c);
        //system.debug(oli.Product2ID);            
    }

}

public PageReference createRelatedServices(){

    List<Related_Service__c> relatedServicesToInsert = new List<Related_Service__c>();

    if(selections != null && selections.size() > 0){
        //Strings of the service name will be returned - match them up with the ID of that service using our map
        for (integer i = 0; i < selections.size(); i++){
            ID serviceToRelateID = ServicesNameToID.get(selections[i]);

            Related_Service__c rs = new Related_Service__c();
            rs.Milestone__c = milestone.ID;
            rs.Service__c = serviceToRelateID;
            rs.Name = 'test';
            relatedServicesToInsert.add(rs);
        }
    }

    insert relatedServicesToInsert;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + milestone.ID);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
  }
}
```

Comment: Move your questio to https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're most probably running into an error. Try adding <apex:pageMessages /> tag on your VF page to see if any errors show up.

Comment: @marioruiz its proper SF question and deserves to be here. Questions about Salesforce Stackexchange needs to be on Meta.

Comment: @AayushK thank you, after adding the pageMessages I saw that it was an issue with my selection string array not being initialized properly. After doing so it works. This can be closed.

Comment: Great. I've moved my comment to the answer section so that you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the comment to the answer so that it can be marked as answered.

You're most probably running into an error. Try adding `<apex:pageMessages />` tag on your VF page to see if any errors show up.